# AJAX with HTML?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

I have a email system I am building for a company that they want to send emails with it. I have a custom HTML editor for it. What I am wanting to do it post the contents to a external PHP file and have it add to the database.

```
function schedule_eblast (html) {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to start sending this E-blast?");
    if (answer) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./../../../processes/eblast_schedule.php",
            data: {'html_text': html},
            success: function(theRetrievedData) {
                if (theRetrievedData == "done") {
                alert("Your eblast has been successfully scheduled to send. To check it's status, go to the manage eblasts page.");
            } else {
                alert(theRetrievedData);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And here is what I have for the header in the eblast_schedule.php file:

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');

    if ((isset($_POST['html_text'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['html_text'])) > 0)) {
        $html_text = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['html_text']));
    } else {
        $html_text = "";
    }
    if ((isset($_POST['subject'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['subject'])) > 0)) {
        $subject = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['subject']));
    } else {
        $subject = "";
    }
    ob_start();
```

And yes, it does get called. But when outputting `html_text`, it removes all the HTML. And when adding to the database, it doesn't show the HTML either.

Help! Thanks.

Comment: How can it show HTML when you `trim`, `stripslashes`, `strip_tags` it?

Comment: Brain fart... You have no idea how stupid I feel now. Thanks for pointing it out! Maybe I need more sleep...

Comment: what is sleep :)? Check my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove those functions and add `mysql_real_escape_string` and it should work fine...

```
include('connect.php');

if ((isset($_POST['html_text'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['html_text'])) > 0)) {
    $html_text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['html_text']);
} else {
    $html_text = "";
}
if ((isset($_POST['subject'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['subject'])) > 0)) {
    $subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']);
} else {
    $subject = "";
}
ob_start();
```